# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException after upgrading Plat Framework 1.2.7 to 1.5.2

Tags: mysql, hibernate, playframework

I needed to update my Play Framework 1 application because of Java and distribution updates on my servers.

After doing the necessary changes for JDK 1.8 everything seems to work. However, when inserting a new record I get the following error.

```
08:49:44,922 ERROR ~ Error during device update (Job): org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1440)
    at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:58)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.create(GenericModel.java:375)
    at models.Device.createDevice(Device.java:154)
    at logic.helpers.DevicePerformer.doJobWithResult(DevicePerformer.java:104)
    at logic.helpers.DevicePerformer.doJobWithResult(DevicePerformer.java:1)
    at play.jobs.Job$2.apply(Job.java:224)
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:285)
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withinFilter(JPA.java:238)
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin$TransactionalFilter.withinFilter(JPAPlugin.java:304)
    at play.jobs.Job.withinFilter(Job.java:201)
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:220)
    at play.jobs.Job$1.call(Job.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3171)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3686)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '215' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 27 more
```

MySQL tells me that the next index is 44806, which is what I expect.

I have two server, and when only running the old code (Play 1.2.7) it works fine and gives me an ID as expected. Both servers use the same database.

It is the new implementation that gives the low value (215 in the example below) so must not use the value in the database but something else.I did notice a table called hibernate_sequence with a 'next_val' field which does give a value close to the 215. It has 25 rows with that one column with all the same numbers.

Has something changed with the new Hibernate implementation so that I need to change something to use the 'Next autoindex' again?

Answer (score 0):

The difference was that with Hibernate 5 not specifying the Generation strategy results in Hibernate using its own.

Using the MySQL values can be done by the following annotation:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```